# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to resolve bare specifier '@microsoft/signalr'

Tags: typescript, signalr, specifier, bare

I want to use signalR in RazorPages web

In typescript file:
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";

```
Create a connection to hub.
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/hub")
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
       .build();
```

I got a error when run
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to resolve bare specifier '@microsoft/signalr' from http://localhost:5000/scripts/index.js?

Please help me, thanks!